# Is there any law protecting me from the people that distrubute a video of me falling the stairs and shared without my permision?

Tags: privacy, california, right-of-publicity

From California, US.
I fell from the stairs at work last week, even if the fall looked terrible on video I managed to not brake anything but just damaged ligaments and some body, visit ER, claim WC and just got 2 days off even when I'm not totally healed.
The point is the video from the security footage was available and got hold of it, I did the terrible mistake of sharing with the person who was with me on the moment of the accident, since none of us can at some point figure out how exactly that happen, he shared the video with a co-worker, who show it around campus and possibly shared too.
The VP of my area shared that video too with the heads of departments.
Now since that happen everybody had been joking with me, people who I don't even know their names come to me to comment about the video and joke about not falling again.
Reported to HR and they just say they will talk with head of departments, I don't think is good enough if is ppl who will not be accounted responsible.

Comment: Rights of personality or publicity are only not a thing in most US states.

Answer (score 6):

> It is any law protecting me from the people that distrubute a video of me falling the stairs and shared without my permision?

No. Your permission is not necessary for distributing or watching that video.

The recording was from your workplace, where your entitlement to privacy is quite limited unlike few settings such as (1) your attorney's office in the course of obtaining legal advice for which the disclosure was needed, or (2) your home.

Even if such an entitlement existed, your decision to share that recording with the person who was with you generally constitutes a waiver of your right to privacy *regarding that incident*. The waiver would apply even if California had some legislation akin to the EU's GDPR. Your description nowhere indicates that that person had a statutory or equitable duty of confidentiality.

It is also highly doubtful that you would wish to block the distribution of the video if people instead of mocking you expressed something pleasant or encouraging to you.

> people who I don't even know their names come to me to comment about the video and joke about not falling again.

That is not unlawful in and of itself.

Since the matter does not involve a protected category such as sex, race, religion, or disability, pursuing a claim of hostile work environment would be quite a stretch. It would also be futile because any relief would not cover outsiders who watch the video and feel like joking about it.

The notion of harassment entails a *pattern* of conduct (meaning that a person engages twice or more in that conduct) that causes a reasonable person to feel annoyed or concerned for his safety. Even if someone engages makes a few jokes that cause you to get annoyed, any petition for restraining orders seems unlikely to succeed.

Sooner rather than later, the jokes will get old and people will move on.

Comment: The injury caused by falling down the stairs arguably is a (temporary) disability.

Comment: @nick012000 but unless you broke your legs irreparably, it's not under the ADA

Comment: The right of publicity might apply if the video were used to, for example, promote a business in its commercials. Still, generally speaking, your analysis is sound.

Comment: @Trish: Under the ADA Amendments Act, disabilities that are both transitory (less than 6 months) and minor are not covered.  However, it's possible that a broken leg is transitory and severe, in which case it may be covered.  See also question 25 on https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/guidance/questions-and-answers-final-rule-implementing-ada-amendments-act-2008 .

Comment: @Brian Even if the disability warranted an anti-discrimination assessment, the matter seems very unlikely to withstand the criteria outlined in [*Harris v. Forklift Systems, Inc*, 510 US 17, 23 (1993)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1993527510us171524). For instance, the OP's mention of "*joke[s] about not falling again*" does not purport that he is/was the target of "*offensive utterance[s]*", let alone of conduct that "*is physically threatening or humiliating*" or that interferes with his work performance.

Comment: @IñakiViggers: I agree.  I was specifically disagreeing with Trish that a temporary broken leg definitely wouldn't be protected by the ADA.  I was not claiming that OP's experience was a violation of the ADA.  My intent was to make a technical correction, not to advise OP.